# RPM %post as a different user

Tags: bash, rpm

I need to run a command as a different user in the %post section of an RPM.

At the moment I am using a bit of a hack via python but it can't be the best way (it does feel a little dirty) ...

```
%post -p /usr/bin/python
import os, pwd, subprocess
os.setuid(pwd.getpwnam('apache')[2])
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/something', 'an arg'])
```

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Use `sudo -u user command args` or `su user -c command args` ?

Comment: More detail, please. Something that must run under user `apache` should probably use `setuid`.

Comment: This is a bundled PHP script that needs to be called.  I can't use su as Apache does not have a shell. Although sudo might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/usr/bin/something` is something you are installing as part of the package, install it with something like

```
attr(4755, apache, apache)   /usr/bin/something
```

When installed like this, `/usr/bin/something` will *always* run as user `apache`, regardless of what user actually runs it.

Comment: Just to clarify what this does, it adds the setuid bit to `/usr/bin/something` so that when you later call it, it will run with the privileges of the owner of the file instead of the invoking user's privileges. This is not suitable for general use; at a minimum, you definitely should understand the security implications of adding a new setuid script to the system.

Comment: Also, since `apache` is a service account, created specifically to own Apache-related files, it's unlikely the `apache` user can do much beyond run `/usr/bin/something` et al.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer here is wrong IMO. It is not often at all you want to set attributes to allow *anyone* execute something as the owner.

If you want to run something as a specific user, and that user doesn't have a shell set, you can use `su -s` to set the shell to use.

For example: `su -s /bin/bash apache -c "/usr/bin/something an arg"`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the question in the title. In short, `su -c '/usr/bin/something "an arg"' apache` does what you are asking, and the addition of the `-s /bin/bash` (or often just `-s /bin/sh` instead) is necessary if the `apache` user is configured to not have a shell (as is often the case for system accounts).