# Run rpmbuild %post bash script as non-root user

Tags: bash, rpmbuild

I've been tring to build RPM pakage, that run bash script as non-root user.

For now i've been tring the following steps:

1. Create another script as showing:

   ```
    sudo -u USER -c "call to my script"
   ```

Error: sudo cammand not found

2. Under %post:

   attr(4755, USER, GROUP) call to my script

Error: syntax error near unexpected token `4755,'

tnx :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RPM %post as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653147/rpm-post-as-a-different-user)

Comment: Thanks for response, but no...
this is the second try

Comment: Sure it does, the _accepted_ answer doesn't tell you how to solve this but the other answer there shows you exactly how to do it.

Comment: Well, it dosnt run with the right user, so whay are you close my question?

Comment: If you tried `su` like in the linked question's other answer and it didn't work, please [edit] your question to ask about that instead, with enough details to provide a [mre], or explain why this solution is not acceptable to you.

Comment: The `attr` command sets the attributes of a file; it does not call any script.